# How to update a GemFire Region based on changes in some other Region

Tags: microservices, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

My retail application has various contexts like receive, transfer etc. The requests to these contexts are handled by RESTful microservices developed using *Spring Boot*. The persistence layer is Cassandra. This is shared by all services as we couldn't do a vertical scaling for microservices at DB level as the services are tightly coupled conceptually.

We want vertical scaling at GemFire end by creating different Regions for different contexts.

For example, a BOX table in Cassandra will be updated by Region Box-Receive(receive context) and Region Box-Transfer(transfer context) via `CacheWriter`.

**Our problem is how to maintain data sync between these two Regions?
Please suggest any other approach also for separation at GemFire end.**

gemfire version-

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.gemstone.gemfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>gemfire</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative approach, since you are using *Spring Boot* would be to do the following:

1. First annotation your `@SpringBootApplication` class with [`@EnableGemfireCacheTransactions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/transaction/config/EnableGemfireCacheTransactions.html)...

Example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableGemfireCacheTransactions
@EnableGemfireRepositories
class YourSpringBootApplication { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourSpringBootApplication.class, args);
    }

    ...
}
```

The `@EnableGemfireCacheTransactions` annotation enables *Spring Data GemFire's* [`GemfireTransactionManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/transaction/GemfireTransactionManager.html), which integrates GemFire's [`CacheTransactionManager`](http://gemfire-91-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheTransactionManager.html) with [*Spring Transaction Management* infrastructure](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction) which then allows you to do this...

2. Now, just annotate your `@Service` application component transactional service methods with core *Spring's* `@Transactional` annotation, like so...

   @Service
   class YourBoxReceiverTransferService {

   ```
   @Transactional
   public <return-type> update(ReceiveContext receiveContext, 
           TransferContext transferContext {

       ...
       receiveContextRepository.save(receiveContext);
       transferContextRepository.save(transferContext);
       ...
   }
   ```

   }

As you can see here, I also used [*Spring Data (GemFire's) Repository*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#gemfire-repositories) infrastructure to manage the persistence operations (e.g. CRUD), which will be used appropriately in the transactional scoped-context setup by *Spring*.

2 advantages with the *Spring* approach, over using GemFire's public API, which unnecessarily couples you to GemFire (a definite code smell, particularly in a *Spring* context), is...

1. You don't have to place a bunch of boilerplate, crap code in to your application components, which does **not** belong there!
2. Using *Spring's Transaction Management* infrastructure, it is extremely easy to change your *Transaction Management Strategy*, such as by switching from GemFire's local-only cache transactions, to say, Global, **JTA-based Transactions** if the need every arises (such as, oh, well, now I need to send a message over a JMS message queue after the GemFire Region's and Cassandra BOX Table are updated to notify some downstream process that the Receiver/Transfer context has been updated).  With *Spring's Transaction Management* infrastructure, you **do not** need to change a single line of application code to change transaction management strategies (such as local to global, or global to local, etc).

Hope this helps!

-John

Answer (score 0):

You can use [transactions](http://gemfire82.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/transactions/chapter_overview.html). Something like this should work:

```
txMgr = cache.getTransactionManager();
txMgr.begin();
boxReceive.put();
...
boxtransfer.put();
txMgr.commit();
```

This will work provided you [co-locate](http://gemfire82.docs.pivotal.io/docs-gemfire/latest/developing/partitioned_regions/colocating_partitioned_region_data.html) the box-receive and the box-transfer region and use the same key, or use a PartitionResolver to colocate the data.